# Jhipster Spring Social SignIn with Facebook and Google not working

Tags: facebook, jhipster, spring-social, facebook-social-plugins, google-plus-signin

I'm developing a Jhipster based application with Angularjs. When I click to login with Facebook or Google then popup appear for choose account after that it through a blank page with URL /signin?error=provider'.

[image: comes this page after choose account from popup]

I've already created an application with Google developer and Facebook developer account. and pasted there key and app id in the application.yml file.

There is a warning at my browser console -

[image]

Information shows in the network tab
[image]

and in another process shows

Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: no error in my browser console, just a warning which I added in my question now.

Comment: request status also added in question, please check now..